# Maximum value of back emf in dc motor?

Tags: dc-motor

I have already been searching for this but couldn't find something reasonable

I want to know that when  will be the value of back emf maximum in a dc motor? 
At no load or full load or half load?

Comment: Actually back EMF is maximum at *negative* load ... when something is pulling the motor round faster than its no-load speed. But then it's just called "emf" and the motor isn't a motor any more - it's a generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The back EMF is proportional to speed. As the load increases, the speed will decrease. That will cause the back EMF to decrease. Note that there is a voltage drop across the armature resistance. That voltage drop plus the back EMF is equal to the supply voltage.

Comment: You mean no load is answer?

Comment: Yes, I mean no-load is the answer.